# Use an object indexes to define a possible types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I know that we can extract type possibilies using an array:

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana'] as const
type fruitType = typeof fruits[number] // "Apple" | "Pear" | "Banana"
```

I wonder if we can do this using object indexes instead?

```js
const fruits = {
  apple: { shape: 'round', color: 'red' },
  pear: { shape: 'pear-like', color: 'yellow' },
  banana: { shape: 'banana-shaped', color: 'banana-colored' }
}
type fruitType = typeof indexes of fruits // "apple" | "pear" | "banana"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Those are generally termed "keys", not "indexes", when applied to objects. Thus the keyword in TypeScript `keyof`...

Comment: It looks very strange. Usually the union type is used fro those puposes - type fruitTypes =  'Apple' | 'Pear' | 'Banana'. Then that type is implemented for both const fruits: fruitTypes  and const fruits: { [key: fruitTypes]: unknown };

Comment: you mean this ? ```type keys = keyof typeof fruits;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
type fruitType = keyof typeof fruits // "apple" | "pear" | "banana";
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) as @jcalz suggested, and the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EsoRgXhgbwLABQMMAhgA5kA2ApgFy4wQAW5dMA5AiEmACbsAaGKEogE9TtX4wAvgMLEy1EuIbNWEpSoC0lFAGtqg4SFGr2AT2qVRAd3az5RGACMSYdyXo5GLJRLcPD211JX4hETEAz2DIhCkHGUIZAG5CQigLJRhDCwxsXJA4GEylIvhkNAwAemqOciojGAAfDi0EB1b2QM92FKA)

Comment: Consider linking to [the handbook documentation for the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)